# Authentication problem in Ruby Sinatra web app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app with two controllers and api helper

```rb
# ApplicationController

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension
  helpers ApiHelper

  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end

  before do
    content_type :json
  end

  get '/hello' do
    { message: 'Hello!' }.to_json
  end
end
```

```rb
# ArticlesController

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before do
    authenticate!
  end

  get '/articles' do
    articles = Article.all
    articles.map { |article| serialize(article) }
  end

  ...
end
```

```rb
# ApiHelper

module ApiHelper
  def authenticate!
    halt 403, { message: 'Unauthorized!' }.to_json unless authorized?
  end

  private

  def authorized?
    request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] == 'Bearer 123qweasd'
  end
end
```

When I do

```
curl -X GET -i -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:4567/hello
```

to do helth check I get `403 Unauthorized`. Why? I don't require authentication in `/hello` endpoint, only in `/articles` CRUD endpoints so I don't understand why it authenticates in `/hello`. According to the docs `before` block is used to perform some action before other action runs but I don't call `authenticate!` in `before` block in `ApplicationController`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that not knowingly I was using `ArticlesController` as a middleware. My `config.ru` looked like this.

```rb
run ApplicationController
use ArticlesController
```

which made it so that the `authenticate!` was called before every request.

I changed my `config.ru` to this:

```rb
map '/' do
  run ApplicationController
end

map '/articles' do
  run ArticlesController
end
```

And it works.